# Display the default discounted price and percentage on Woocommerce products

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, percentage, price

I am trying to display the percentage discount of a product on Woocommerce. The solution originally provided (linked below) works, however the discount percentage doesn't display if there is a default product variation set. Only when the selection is changed to another variation does the percentage discount appear. How would I modify the code to display the percent discount immidiately - without having to select another variation?

Source code: 
[Display the discounted price and percentage on Woocommerce products](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48480480/display-the-discounted-price-and-percentage-on-woocommerce-products/48482026#48482026) *(option 2)*

2) The saving percentage:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html',     'change_displayed_sale_price_html', 10, 2 );
function change_displayed_sale_price_html( $price, $product ) {
     // Only on sale products on frontend and excluding min/max price on variable products
    if( $product->is_on_sale() && ! is_admin() && ! $product->is_type('variable')){
         // Get product prices
         $regular_price = (float) $product->get_regular_price(); // Regular price
         $sale_price = (float) $product->get_price(); // Active price (the "Sale price" when on-sale)

         // "Saving Percentage" calculation and formatting
         $precision = 1; // Max number of decimals
         $saving_percentage = round( 100 - ( $sale_price / $regular_price * 100 ), 1 ) . '%';

         // Append to the formated html price
         $price .= sprintf( __('<p class="saved-sale">Save: %s</p>', 'woocommerce' ), $saving_percentage );
    }
    return $price;
}
```

Comment: Answer didn't work, maybe checking `if get_price == 0` and then looking at `get_variation_price('min')` to see if you can get a price from there. `get_regular_price()` may also be returning 0

Comment: Sorry but the code works also when there is a default selected variation (on sale) and displays the discount percentage…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The [linked code works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48480480/display-the-discounted-price-and-percentage-on-woocommerce-products/48482026#48482026) also when there is a default selected variation (on sale) for the variable product and displays the discount percentage correctly…
>
> Now for the variable product general displayed price range, **you can't display a discounted percentage**, as all variations should need to be on sale and each variation discounted percentage can be different…

For selected **product variations on sale** price, you can also use the following to get the saving percentage:

```
// For product variations
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_variation', 'custom_variation_price_saving_percentage', 10, 3 );
function custom_variation_price_saving_percentage( $data, $product, $variation ) {
    $active_price  = $data['display_price'];
    $regular_price = $data['display_regular_price'];

    if( $active_price !== $regular_price ) {
        $saving_percentage = round( 100 - ( $active_price / $regular_price * 100 ), 1 ) . '%';
        $data['price_html'] .= sprintf( __('<p class="saved-sale">Save: %s</p>', 'woocommerce' ), $saving_percentage );
    }
    return $data;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme).

Then for simple products you will use:

```
// For simple products
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'change_displayed_sale_price_html', 10, 2 );
function change_displayed_sale_price_html( $price, $product ) {
     // Only on sale products on frontend and excluding min/max price on variable products
    if( $product->is_on_sale() && ! is_admin() && $product->is_type('simple') ){
         // Get product prices
         $regular_price = (float) $product->get_regular_price(); // Regular price
         $sale_price = (float) $product->get_price(); // Active price (the "Sale price" when on-sale)

         // "Saving Percentage" calculation and formatting
         $precision = 1; // Max number of decimals
         $saving_percentage = round( 100 - ( $sale_price / $regular_price * 100 ), $precision ) . '%';

         // Append to the formated html price
         $price .= sprintf( __('<p class="saved-sale">Save: %s</p>', 'woocommerce' ), $saving_percentage );
    }
    return $price;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme).