# Change custom discount price percentage styling in WooCommerce single products

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce, product, discount

I am using *"[Display the default discounted price and percentage on Woocommerce products](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54375409/display-the-default-discounted-price-and-percentage-on-woocommerce-products/54375782#54375782)"* answer code (for simple products), and I would like the displayed output font to be bold, red and with a large size, for this line:

```
sprintf( __('<p class="saved-sale">Save: %s <em>(%s)</em></p>', 'woocommerce' ), $saving_price, $saving_percentage );
```

How this can be done? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would target the paragraph element with the class **.saved-sale**.

In your CSS you could write something like this:

```
p.saved-sale {
 font-weight: bold;
 color: FF0000;
 font-size: larger;
}
```

Check out [font-size on the MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-size) to learn how to increase or decrease font sizes.