# Display 'you savex%' in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I have a Wocommerce store that has variable and simple products.

I don't want to show '% you save' save in simple products.

I am using *"[Display the default discounted price and percentage on Woocommerce products](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54375409/display-the-default-discounted-price-and-percentage-on-woocommerce-products/54375782#54375782)"*.

How to block discount % in simple products?

Comment: As explained on the original thread just use the first code snippet not the second one that is for simple products.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for your case. This will exclude products that are `'simple'` .

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_variation', 'custom_variation_price_saving_percentage', 10, 3 );
    function custom_variation_price_saving_percentage( $data, $product, $variation ) {
        global $product;
        $active_price  = $data['display_price'];
        $regular_price = $data['display_regular_price'];

        if( $active_price !== $regular_price && !$product->is_type('simple') {
            $saving_percentage = round( 100 - ( $active_price / $regular_price * 100 ), 1 ) . '%';
            $data['price_html'] .= sprintf( __('<p class="saved-sale">Save: %s</p>', 'woocommerce' ), $saving_percentage );
        }
        return $data;
    }
```

Comment: I am using the 'WooCommerce Dynamic Pricing & Discounts' of **RightPress**
The discount is made on the fly with this plugin, that means the plugin does not insert the discount into the product's field in the dashborad. The question is how to apply the discount to the simple product with the same  function.

Comment: The simple question is how to not exclude the simple product from the 'You Safe' function.