# How to display Percent instead of Sale on Woocommerce Product Tag Box

Tags: php, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

My home page contains a woocommerce product tag box. I tried to change the sale button so that percent appears instead. I work with Astra Theme.

I have tried [Display the default discounted price and percentage on Woocommerce products](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54375409/display-the-default-discounted-price-and-percentage-on-woocommerce-products/54375782#54375782) answer code, but I don't work on my page.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following to add the saving percentage on the Sale Badge:

```php
// On sale badge with saving percentage (for simple, variable and grouped products)
add_filter( 'woocommerce_sale_flash', 'on_sale_badge_saving_percentage', 20, 3 );
function on_sale_badge_saving_percentage( $html, $post, $product ) {
    $text_prefix = __("Save", 'woocommerce') . ' ';
    $percentages = array(); // Initializing

    if ($product->is_type('variable')) {
        $prices      = $product->get_variation_prices();

        // Loop through variation prices
        foreach ( $prices['price'] as $key => $price ) {
            $regular_price = (float) $prices['regular_price'][$key];
            $active_price  = (float) $price;
            // Only on sale variations
            if ( $regular_price > $active_price )  {
                // Calculate and set in the array the percentage for each variation on sale
                $percentages[] = ( $regular_price - $active_price ) / $regular_price * 100;
            }
        }
        $percentage = round( max($percentages), 0 ) . '%'; // We keep the highest value  <===  Missing round()
    } 
    elseif ($product->is_type('grouped')) {
        // Get all children products
        $children_products  = array_filter( array_map( 'wc_get_product', $product->get_children() ), 'wc_products_array_filter_visible_grouped' );

        // Loop through children products
        foreach ($children_products as $child_product) {
            if( $child_product->is_on_sale() ) {
                $regular_price = (float) $child_product->get_regular_price();
                $active_price    = (float) $child_product->get_sale_price();
                $percentages[] = 100 - ($active_price / $regular_price * 100); // Add Calculated percentage to the array
            }
        }
        // We keep the highest value
        $percentage = round( max($percentages), 0 ) . '%';
    } else {
        $regular_price = (float) $product->get_regular_price();
        $sale_price    = (float) $product->get_sale_price();

        if ($sale_price != 0 || !empty($sale_price)) {
            $percentage    = round(100 - ($sale_price / $regular_price * 100)) . '%';
        } 
    }
    return sprintf('<span class="onsale">%s</span>', esc_html($text_prefix) . $percentage );
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). Tested and works.

You will get something like (on Storefront theme):

[image]

---

[image]

---

**Note:** For some themes, you will need to use a different proprietary hook.

Comment: I did but It didn't work!

Comment: So this is because of your theme customizations… My code works on most themes, but not your theme. You need to search in the theme support threads, how to customize the sale badge, and to find what is the hook replacement to  `woocommerce_sale_flash` WooCommerce hook.